# Batch of events having different partition key in event hub

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I would like to send a batch of events with different partition key in event hub using python client. I can send a single message with the partition key set but what if I need to send a batch of events containing different partition key to event hub

Here is the code for 1 event

```
message = [{'id': 1, 'msg': 'this is test msg 1'}, 
           {'id': 2, 'msg': 'this is test msg 2'},
           {'id': 3, 'msg': 'this is test msg 3'}]
for msg in message:
 client.run()

 event_data = EventData(msg['msg'])
 event_data.partition_key = str(msg['id'])
 sender.send(event_data)
```

I would like to do the same with batch sending all 3 messages at the same time

Comment: can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: code updated..hav a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's impossible, `send batch method` would send all the events in batch to the same one partition.

Here is the test code, I can specify different partition keys to event data, then send with batch(you can modify it to meet your need):

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Sender, EventData

# use this method to generate event data, and set partition key.
def data_generator():
    for i in range(15):
        data = EventData("hi, hello world!")    
        if i % 2 ==0:    
            data.partition_key=b'0'
        else:
            data.partition_key=b'1'
        temp = data.body_as_str()
        yield temp

ADDRESS = "xxxx"

# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "xxx"

client = EventHubClient(address=ADDRESS,username=USER,password=KEY)
sender = client.add_sender()
client.run()

data = EventData(batch=data_generator())
sender.send(data)
print("*completed*")
```

It sends successfully, but when I read the even data, I can see all the data are actually sent to one same partition.

And if the reason you're using `batch send method` to improve performance, and must use different partition key, you can consider using [send asyn](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/send_async.py)c method to achieve this.

Comment: Got it, yes.. wanted to verify this. thank you. Accepting this as answer

Comment: @Ivan Yang - When I try to do `data.partition_key=b'somevalue'`, I get the error `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I ended up specifying the `partition_key` in the `send_event()` method of the `EventHubProducerClient` class.